# Q Dotproduct of a vector

Tags: javascript, vector, jasmine, dot-product

I have my vector object and am trying to make this pass a few tests.
Firstly the first dotProduct function passes the "is positive test".
But am struggling to make it pass the two other tests of "is negative" and "is zero".

```
var Vector = (function () {
function Vector(pX, pY, pZ) {
    this.setX(pX);
    this.setY(pY);
    this.setZ(pZ);

}
Vector.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.mX;
};
Vector.prototype.setX = function (pX) {
    this.mX = pX;
};
Vector.prototype.getY = function () {
    return this.mY;
};
Vector.prototype.setY = function (pY) {
    this.mY = pY;
};
Vector.prototype.setZ = function () {
    return this.mZ;
};
Vector.prototype.getZ = function (pZ) {
    this.mZ = pZ;
};
Vector.prototype.add = function (v) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() + v.getX(), this.getY() + v.getY());
};
Vector.prototype.subtract = function (s) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() - s.getX(), this.getY() - s.getY());
};
Vector.prototype.multiply = function (scalar) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() * scalar, this.getY() * scalar);
};
Vector.prototype.divide = function (scalar) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() / scalar, this.getY() / scalar);
};
Vector.prototype.magnitude = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.getX() * this.getX() + this.getY() * this.getY());
};
Vector.prototype.normalise = function () {
    return new Vector(this.getX() / this.magnitude(), this.getY() / this.magnitude());
};
Vector.prototype.limitTo = function (Scalar) {
    this.normalise();
    this.multiply(Scalar);
    return new Vector(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getZ());
};

//Vector.prototype.dotProduct = function () {
//    var secondVector = new Vector(100, 400);

//    return new Vector(this.getX() * secondVector.getX() +
//        this.getY() * secondVector.getY());
//};
Vector.prototype.dotProduct = function (secondVector) {
    secondVector = new Vector(-100, -400);

    return new Vector(this.getX() * secondVector.getX() +
        this.getY() * secondVector.getY() / Math.acos(90));
};

return Vector;

}());
```

Test Conditions:

```
describe("Dot Product", function () {

    it("Result is zero", function () {
        var secondVector, dotProduct;
        secondVector = new Vector(40, -30, 0);
        dotProduct = vector.dotProduct(secondVector);

        expect(dotProduct).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Result is positive", function () {
        var secondVector, dotProduct;
        secondVector = new Vector(50, 0, 0);
        dotProduct = vector.dotProduct(secondVector);

        expect(dotProduct).not.toBeLessThan(0);
    });

    it("Result is negative", function () {
        var secondVector, dotProduct;
        secondVector = new Vector(0, -50, 1);
        dotProduct = vector.dotProduct(secondVector);

        expect(dotProduct).toBeLessThan(0);
    });
});
```

This is the first vector that "this" is referring to.

```
housePosition = new Vector(150, 100);
```

This is the description of what the function should do:

"your Vector object should have a ‘dotProduct’ function that takes a single Vector object as its parameter. The function should return a single scalar value that is the result of the dot product of the ‘this’ Vector and the parameter Vector"

Am I going about this correctly?
How would I make it pass these tests? Simply make the vector negative or is there something else I need to do.

Comment: considering that you have 2 dotProduct definitions and in each of them you have secondVector hard-codded to something (and no parameters taken in), your code might be wrong. You may have issues in set/get methods which effectively will render your calculation to always be 0.

Comment: Even with one of them commented out I still only have "is positive" that correctly works.

Comment: in each of them you have hard-codded value for secondVecor, and you are not using any input parameters. As is, these methods dont depend on input in any way. Also, you are not showing your setX and getX methods.

Comment: Added my entire vector object now

Comment: They are given tests that use the chutzpah extension, it uses jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Your set and get methods are ok. Lets take a look at your dotProduct method.

```
Vector.prototype.dotProduct = function () {
    var secondVector = new Vector(100, 400);

    return new Vector(this.getX() * secondVector.getX() +
        this.getY() * secondVector.getY() * Math.acos(90));
};
```

1) it does not use any of the input parameters!

2) it uses a hardcoded vector (100, 400) as a multiplier

3) it returns a new vector object constructed with a.... single parameter of

```
this.getX() * secondVector.getX() +
        this.getY() * secondVector.getY() * Math.acos(90)
```

4) Math.acos(90) returns NaN, cause value of cos is between 1 and -1. Even if you meant to get cosine of an angle, it is still wrong, cause angle units for Math.cos is radians not degrees.

So your result of any dotProduct call is Vector object with mX:NaN and mY:undefined.

Btw, your commented out method for the dotProduct looked more like a dotProduct. You just have to return the number, not a vector. (at least, you are expecting a number in your unit tests). So I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
Vector.prototype.dotProduct = function ( secondVector ) {
    return this.getX()*secondVector.getX() + this.getY()*secondVector.getY();
};
```

Comment: Ah ok so I don't need the Secondvector var, and I need to return a value instead of a vector.

Comment: and you need a correct formulae for the vector dot product. Also it helps to use browser developers console to try and debug your code before writing tests.